# What's the difference between Dell ProSupport/Gold/Silver/MissionCritical/etc. warranties?

Tags: dell, warranty

I'm having trouble finding any documentation on this, but I vaguely remember something about MissionCritical letting you demand them send a tech out "NOW!" before even commencing basic phone support (hence the product name). Can someone clarify exactly what level of service each warranty type gets you?

Comment: as @Bart said. Speak to your dell Rep.

Comment: You know what I do when I have a question like this and I want a clear and accurate answer? I call the vendor. No offense, but I don't understand why you would post this type of question here instead of calling Dell. Why is calling the manufacturer or vendor the last thing people think of when they have questions like this?

Comment: @joeqwerty - because it's a PITA, probably. I avoid even doing tech support via phone if they have the "live support" chat option.

Comment: I think this is the most downvotes a question has ever seen without being closed... Thanks for the love? Edit: this one is - http://serverfault.com/questions/313858/distributing-windows-updates-through-lan-to-save-bandwidth

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/17165000.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics of each support contract can be reviewed on this page:
http://content.dell.com/us/en/business/service-contracts-support-services.aspx

The mission critical warranty upgrade allows for severity level 1 issue designation. Sev-1 issues have technical account manager assignment and monitoring, and in the case of a hardware failure will have best guess parts dispatched ASAP while continuing to troubleshoot over the phone. The severity level is determined by the Dell technician based on certain criteria.

The warranty type that allows the request of an onsite technician for troubleshooting is called Onsite Diagnostics. This is an add-on warranty that can be purchased through your sales representative. Not all equipment, account types, base warranties, and locations qualify for onsite diagnostics.

In the case of the Prosupport with mission critical, you are not able to "demand" that an onsite technician be sent out before commencing troubleshooting. If the issue meets the criteria for severity level-1 and parts are needed then a technician will be dispatched with parts as soon as a best guess on parts can be made. If the issue does not qualify for sev-1 then parts will be dispatched after troubleshooting has been completed. The determination of severity level is based on the function, affected users, and current status. For example, if your company's only exchange server went down then that would be a sev-1 issue. Another example, if an exchange server in a cluster went down and the failover was working correctly then that would not be a sev-1. Lastly, after it is determined that an issue meets the criteria for sev-1 you will be asked if you want it to be sev-1. The technician may not ask specifically if you want to designate this a sev-1, but may instead ask if you are willing to be onsite and work with us until the issue is resolved. Sev-1 requires that someone be available onsite until resolution.

Comment: +1 for the link to the documentation (which I couldn't find via clicking around)

Answer (score 3):

Normally if you're ordering from Dell with higher end support needed, you should have a representative assigned to you. Your sales rep would give you the latest terms and conditions. If you're looking for that kind of support, they'll be MORE than willing to work with you on it. Plus you can negotiate a price for hardware/services.

Their advertised pricing, it turns out, can be very flexible when you have a one-on-one sales rep to "discuss" your needs.